# Karate DSL : How to check if the JSON object is optional, but if that object comes the keys inside that object should be of correct schema?

Tags: karate

I want to validate a JSON schema where an object in a nested JSON response is optional but if the object comes the keys in that object should also come.

Sample Response :-

```
{
    "id" : "1234",
    "targetPhoneNumber" : "1234",
    "paid" : { //optional
      "units" : "asd", //mandatory if the paid object is coming
      "amount" : 12.00 //mandatory if the paid object is coming
    },
    "date" : "2019",
    "boolean" : false,
    "transactionId" : "1234"
  }
```

I need schema checks for these cases.

1) If the paid object is coming it should be a JSON object and should contains units as string and amount as mandatory.
2) If the paid object is not coming still the schema validation should pass.

Answer (score 3):

Combining ['self' validation expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions) and `karate.match(actual, expected)` API gives some way to achieve this,

This should work,

```
* def schema =
"""
{
      "boolean": "#boolean",
      "date": "#string",
      "id": "#string",
      "paid": "##object? karate.match(_,{\"amount\": \"#number\",\"units\": \"#string\"}).pass",
      "targetPhoneNumber": "#string",
      "transactionId": "#string"
}
"""
```

If you don't want to add your subSchema inline / if your subschema is too large you can try this

```
* def passSchema =
"""
{
    "amount": "#number",
    "units": "#string"
}
"""
* def schema =
"""
{
    "boolean": "#boolean",
    "date": "#string",
    "id": "#string",
    "paid": "##object? karate.match(_,passSchema).pass",
    "targetPhoneNumber": "#string",
    "transactionId": "#string"
}
"""
```

**Simple JSON schema:**

```
{
      "boolean": "#boolean",
      "date": "#string",
      "id": "#string",
      "paid": "##object? karate.match(_,{\"amount\": \"#number\",\"units\": \"#string\"}).pass",
      "targetPhoneNumber": "#string",
      "transactionId": "#string"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Babu thanks for the reply! But I have stored all my schemas in different JSON files and using def would not work in my case. Is there any way I can define such use case in the JSON and then call in the feature file to validate ?

Comment: @abhii2628, you simply use the value in schema in a json file, anyways updated the answer.

Comment: I mean store the Simple JSON schema value from the updated answer in a json file

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Babu, it worked for me . I wasn't aware if the entire JS function could be used with escaping the characters. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this with conditionals:

```
* def outerMatcher =
"""
{
"id" : "#string",
"targetPhoneNumber" : "#string",
"paid" : "##object",
"date" : "#string",
"boolean" : "#boolean",
"transactionId" : "#string"
}
"""

* def paidMatcher =
"""
{
  "units": "#string",
  "amount": "#number"
}
"""

* def innerMatcher = karate.match(response.paid, "#object").pass ? paidMatcher : "#notpresent"

* match response == outerMatcher
* match response.paid == innerMatcher
```