# How can I do a structural match to check an optional element (subtree) in xml

Tags: xml, schema, karate

I have seen examples like this for json that show how to handle an optional object (subtree):

[Karate DSL : How to check if the JSON object is optional, but if that object comes the keys inside that object should be of correct schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096758/karate-dsl-how-to-check-if-the-json-object-is-optional-but-if-that-object-com/54097389)

How do I accomplish something similar for an optional xml element, which may be the root of an entire subtree?

From examples like this I get the impression support for xml is not as strong as for json and I may need to convert xml to json?

To make it more concrete, an address can have a street name and a number. But the number can have an additional **optional** suffix, like "A", "B", "C", or "-302" (floor 3, apartment 2).

So I could have

```
<address>
  <streetname>Deurningerstraat</streetname>
  <housenumber>1</housenumber>
  <suffix>303</suffix>                      <<<=== optional element
  <city>...</city>
  <zipcode>...</zipcode>
  <country>...</country>
<address>
```

Comment: refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1321

Comment: thanks also for the link to where a similar question was answered

Comment: no problem. the moderators just deleted my answers here twice because they care more about the rules than actually helping people

Comment: Off topic here, but I've already quite a lot working:
I can execute commands in a shell and see the return value.
I can use a tcp connection to get back a soap result from our server.
I can access MySql database on my laptop and Oracle database on company server. I wrote Java code to return an ArrayList of map<String, Object> from the result set. I saw your code that uses spring framework, but mine does not have such dependencies.
I wrote Java code also for reading csv files. I can pass a field separator, quote character, a boolean flag usesDecimalComma (if false it uses a dot).
Thanks.