# Karate Schema JSON Validation with incremental 'key name'

Tags: karate

Into my json schema i need to manage keys with 'incremental' name :

For example :

```
  [
   {
        "id": 9396,
        "value": "toto",
        "attribut": "blue",
        "occur1": null,
        "occur2": null,
        "occur3": null,
        "occur4": null,
        "occur5": null,
        "occur6": null,
        "occur7": null,
        "occur8": {
            "occurenceId": 105498,
            "year": "2023",
            "quantity": 707
        },
        "occur9": {
            "occurenceId": 105499,
            "year": "2023",
            "quantity": 371
        },
        "occur10": {
            "occurenceId": 105500,
            "year": "2023",
            "quantity": 875
        },
        "occur11": null,
        "occur12": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9417,
        "value": "momo",
        "attribut": "red",
        "occur1": {
            "occurenceId": 105502,
            "year": "2023",
            "quantity": 85
        },
        "occur2": null,
        "occur3": {
            "occurenceId": 105503,
            "year": "2023",
            "quantity": 432
        },
        "occur4": null,
        "occur5": null,
        "occur6": null,
        "occur7": null,
        "occur8": null,
        "occur9": null,
        "occur10": null,
        "occur11": null,
        "occur12": null
    }
 ]
```

How to manage each key "occur" from occur1 to occur12 wihtout writing each lines with its own schema ?

I tried only by keeping the complete structure :

```
 * def MyStruct =
  """
  { 
    id: '#number',
    value: '#number',
    attribut: '#string',
    occur1: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur2: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur3: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur4: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur5: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur6: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur7: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur8: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur9: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur10: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur11: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })',
    occur12: '##({occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' })'
  }
```

but i would like to know if it is possible to define dynamically the key 'occur(i)' to get something more elegant and flexible if tomorrow i need to increase the number of occurencies.

Thanks

Comment: next time please a) format your question and b) simplify the example, I'm sure you can convey the need without asking people to read your entire JSON dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a much cleaner solution for you. It should give you hints to come up with the final approach you are comfortable with.

```
* def response = 
"""
{
  id: 9417,
  value: 'momo',
  attribut: 'red',
  occur1: {
    occurenceId: 105502,
    year: '2023',
    quantity: 85
  },
  occur2: null,
  occur3: {
    occurenceId: 105503,
    year: '2023',
    quantity: 432
  },
  occur4: null,
  occur5: null
}
"""    
* def items = []
* karate.forEach(response, (k, v) => { if (k.startsWith('occur') && v) items.push(v) })
* match each items == { occurenceId: '#number', year: '#string', quantity: '#number' }
```

For some similar ideas, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912833/143475

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll take note of your comments. I found a solution which is not exactly similar to your solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096758/karate-dsl-how-to-check-if-the-json-object-is-optional-but-if-that-object-com

Comment: @Lolo sure - also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers